# showing $f(z) = \bar{z}^2$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

showing $f(z) = \bar{z}^2$ is differentiable at $0$

from definition we must consider the limit

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\bar{h}^2 }{h}$$ but I'm having troubles evaluating this limit

Comment: write $h = t + is$ where $t, s \in \mathbb R$

Comment: $$\left|\frac{\bar z^2}z\right|=\left|z\right|\to0$$

Comment: @N.H. What for?

Comment: I write without thinking ...

Comment: @did why are you considering the modulus

Comment: I also don't see how you got that expression

Comment: What Did wrote is that the modulus of your fraction tends to $0$, and this means that the fraction itself must tend to $0$.

Comment: "I also don't see how you got that expression" ?? The first ratio is in your question itself. If what you cannot see is that the modulus of the first ratio is $|z|$, then there is some serious gap in your knowledge of basic properties of complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\lim_{h\to0} g(h)=0$ iff $\lim_{h\to0} |g(h)|=0$. For every complex function $g$ defined on a neighborhood of zero(except perhaps zero itself).
Now take $g(h)=\frac{\bar h^2}{h}$ and use the above observation.